# Launcher Activity Not Starting it's Crash

Tags: java, android, program-entry-point, launcher

Launcher Activity Not Starting it's crash when pressed Run Button in Android Studio. Although there not much of code there but still. I have pasted logcat below its take me to the MainActivity at  `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`
I have tried adding

```
`res/color/abc_hint_foreground_material_dark.xml`
```

to the directory but still getting Error, while ago i posted screen shot got 3 VoteDown but that didn't solve my problem, if you don't know please don't bother.while posting this question stackover flow keep asking me to add more details what should I add more ?

```
11-06 17:06:02.890 21445-21445/com.dekhou.UrduKeyboard E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     Process: com.dekhou.UrduKeyboard, PID: 21445
                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dekhou.UrduKeyboard/com.dekhou.UrduKeyboard.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/color/abc_hint_foreground_material_dark.xml from color state list resource ID #0x7f0c0050
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2432)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2492)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1358)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5458)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
                                                                      Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/color/abc_hint_foreground_material_dark.xml from color state list resource ID #0x7f0c0050
                                                                         at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateListForCookie(Resources.java:2810)
                                                                         at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateList(Resources.java:2759)
                                                                         at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:487)
                                                                         at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:749)
                                                                         at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:674)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:62)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:58)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:54)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.setTitle(Toolbar.java:756)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.setTitleInt(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:261)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.setWindowTitle(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:243)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.setWindowTitle(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:615)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onTitleChanged(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:636)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:333)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:289)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                         at com.dekhou.UrduKeyboard.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6323)
                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2385)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2492) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1358) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5458) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628) 
                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: "0.70000005dip"
                                                                         at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
                                                                         at java.lang.StringToReal.initialParse(StringToReal.java:164)
                                                                         at java.lang.StringToReal.parseFloat(StringToReal.java:323)
                                                                         at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:306)
                                                                         at android.content.res.TypedArray.getFloat(TypedArray.java:398)
                                                                         at android.content.res.ColorStateList.inflate(ColorStateList.java:275)
                                                                         at android.content.res.ColorStateList.createFromXmlInner(ColorStateList.java:222)
                                                                         at android.content.res.ColorStateList.createFromXml(ColorStateList.java:201)
                                                                         at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateListForCookie(Resources.java:2806)
                                                                         at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateList(Resources.java:2759) 
                                                                         at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:487) 
                                                                         at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:749) 
                                                                         at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:674) 
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:62) 
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:58) 
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:54) 
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.setTitle(Toolbar.java:756) 
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.setTitleInt(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:261) 
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.setWindowTitle(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:243) 
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.setWindowTitle(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:615) 
                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onTitleChanged(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:636) 
                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:333) 
                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:289) 
                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                         at com.dekhou.UrduKeyboard.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28) 
                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6323) 
                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2385) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2492) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1358) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5458) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)'
```

abc_hint_foreground_material_dark.xml

```
<item android:alpha="@dimen/hint_pressed_alpha_material_dark" android:color="@color/foreground_material_dark" android:state_pressed="true" android:state_enabled="true"/>

<item android:alpha="@dimen/hint_alpha_material_dark" android:color="@color/foreground_material_dark"/>

</selector>
```

Comment: `Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/color/abc_hint_foreground_material_dark.xml from color state list resource ID #0x7f0c0050`

Comment: show `abc_hint_foreground_material_dark`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on

> ```
> android:alpha="@dimen/hint_alpha_material_dark
> ```

and

> ```
> Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: "0.70000005dip"
> ```

it looks like you're trying to use a dimension as an alpha value. Use a float resource instead, e.g.

```
android:alpha="@integer/hint_alpha_material_dark_float"
```

and in values resources:

```
<item name="hint_alpha_material_dark_float" format="float" type="integer">0.7</item>
```

Comment: I chacked those were unwanted for me so I delete it, it works now.